# Can't connect to remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL Server 2014 for development purposes. To simplify i'm testing inside SQL Server Management Studio using Windows authentication, but i get the error below :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance>
>   Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

I already enabled TCP/IP on SQL Server Configuration Manager. Firewall is disabled.
I can ping the remote hostname. Property 'Allow remote connections to this server' is checked.

Anything more to check ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you search for the error? I mean, there are only [1,863 search results *just on this site*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22A%20network-related%20or%20instance-specific%20error%20occurred%20while%20establishing%20a%20connection%20to%20SQL%20Server.%20%22&mixed=1). Maybe start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18060818/61305).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if your server allows connections via "Allow remote connections to this server" in the database properties page -> Connections.  Make sure you can ping the server from the machine you are trying to connect from to ensure the SQL Server is reachable.  Make sure that port 1433 is open on your SQL Server.